# How to make dependent dropdown list and input text to be able to obtain values to pass mysql

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I am building a calculator (php-html) that gets numbers entered by the user. See my snippet below. The output is one query that loop entries from the database (mysql). The text-box options work expectedly it returns the output from the SQL, but when I add the cascade dropdown list to fetch other parameters, the script just gets failing. Looks to me like the "isset" is not able to check the value passed that was selected from the list.  How would both dropdown list and text-box options work together? I prefer the GET method to obtain values in both cases.

```
   <form action="" method="GET">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
        <label for="">Építésű kategória: </label>
        <input list="lakas" name="lakas" /></label>
        <datalist id="lakas">
          <option value="csúszózsalus">
          <option value="panel-lakás">
          <option value="tégla-építésű">
        </datalist>
        <?php
        if(isset($_GET['lakas'])) {
          echo $_GET['lakas'];
          }
        ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <label for="">Kerület: </label>
            <input type="text" name="stud_id" value="<?php if(isset($_GET['stud_id'])){echo $_GET['stud_id'];}?>"placeholder = "Egy kerület megadása szüséges, pl.: '9'" class="form-control">
        </div>


<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <hr>
        <?php
            $con = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","ingatlan");

            if(isset($_GET['stud_id']))
            {
                $stud_id = $_GET['stud_id'];
                $stud_id2 = $_GET['stud_id2'];
                $stud_id3 = $_GET['stud_id3'];
                $lakas = $_GET['lakas'];
```

Comment: _"Looks to me like the "isset" is not able to check the value passed that was selected from the list."_ - what "list" are you talking about here? You got `<input type="text" name="stud_id"`- that is not a "list", that is a text input field.

Comment: Which part of above code you think is rather datalist? I'm looking to get what's in the ['lakas'] attribute somehow

Comment: Then you need to pre-fill your `lakas` input field with the value from the previous form submission, same as you did with the `stud_id` field.

Comment: OK. How to pre-fill am not getting it

Comment: Well what are you currently doing with the value attribute of your `stud_id` field, there in your code ...? Same principle for this one.